# Rapidminer Multilayer Perceptron Modeling output layer

Tags: neural-network, rapidminer

I am trying to train a multilayer neural network in rapidminer. 
The key to my problem is that I have three nodes on my output layer that I want predict:
(y1,y2,y3) = f(x1,x2,x3) with one hidden node. 
As far as I understood, Rapidminer does not allow to assign a "special role" (e.g. label, id, prediction) to more than one variable.

I am assuming an output layer containing more than one node must be possible to model but how is this done?

Several posts recommended using the "setRole" operator - can you give me any hints on that if it is helpful?

Thank you,

Mat

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple labels as long as the types are of the form label1, label2 etc. Use the Generate Multi-Label Data operator to see an example.

Then use the Loop Labels operator and place the neural network operator within it. This will build as many models as there are labels.